# Google Play Games API returns SIGN_IN_REQUIRED

Tags: java, android, google-signin, google-play-games

I'm trying to implement automating player sign in to Google Play games in my Android app. Firstly, as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin), I try to sign in silently:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    signInSilently();
}

private void signInSilently() {
    mGoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful())
            //everything ok
        else {
            final ApiException exception = (ApiException) task.getException();
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG, "Silent Sign In failure: ", exception);
            if (exception.getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED)
                startSignInIntent();
        }
    });
```

Every time I got an exception with code 4 (CommonStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED). So in this case I try to sign in with ui:

```
private void startSignInIntent() {
    startActivityForResult(mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    if (request == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        final GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // everything is ok, get account from result
        } else if (result.getStatus().hasResolution()) {
            resolveManually(result.getStatus());
        } else {
            String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG, "status code" + result.getStatus().getStatusCode());
            if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                message = "other error";
            }
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And here everytime I get message with other error! The status code is again 4 (CommonStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED). How can I get this code when I try to sign in using intent? So, my app are in infinite loop because onResume is called everytime my activity loads after receiving a result, and everytime the status code is CommonStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED. So, where is the problem?
In Google [samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples) there is no information how can I handle automatic sign in, only manual with sign in buttons. But google [recommends](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPapbl8R9ws) to use automating sign in. Please help anybody to understand what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was wrong OAuth 2.0 client ID for the debug version of my app! Don't know why there is SIGN_IN_REQUIRED status code in this situation, it is really confusing!

Comment: Thank you, this was confusing and not obvious.

Comment: I double checked I have correct debug and release keys. What else could it be?

Answer (score 1):

You must not start the login screen from your onResume method. It is a silent login which works if the user wants it (by tapping a button). That's why the examples show it only this way.

Comment: I don't start login from onResume. mGoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn() tries to sign in without user interaction, so user doesn't see anything. This silent sign in code is [recommended by Google](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin).

Comment: I see this flow in your code: onResume -> signInSilently() -> if signInRequired: startSignInIntent() - so you are calling the non-silent methods from onResume, which is not allowed.

Comment: how does this apply to Flutter? I use games_services package and I'm getting this all the time when trying to show achievements or leaderboard despite I can see my user logged in